# Why isn't autovaccum running/completing?

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, autovacuum, amazon-rds-aurora

My PostgreSQL instance (AWS Aurora) isn't autovacuuming. Or it is, but it is somehow being interrupted or stopped. I'm not canceling any autovacuum queries (though I suppose AWS itself could be).

The phi.claim table has 8M rows. There are ~10k updates/hour. When I vacuum manually, 16-38M row versions are removed:

```
rivet=> vacuum verbose phi.claim;
INFO:  vacuuming "phi.claim"
INFO:  scanned index "claim_pkey" to remove 38136154 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 6.49 s, system: 0.17 s, elapsed: 14.97 s
INFO:  scanned index "claim_claim_set_id_external_id_idx" to remove 38136154 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 13.53 s, system: 0.70 s, elapsed: 113.82 s
INFO:  scanned index "claim_claim_set_id_idx" to remove 38136154 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 9.72 s, system: 0.43 s, elapsed: 62.43 s
INFO:  scanned index "claim_code_modifier_quantities_idx" to remove 38136154 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 77.79 s, system: 3.93 s, elapsed: 617.93 s
INFO:  scanned index "claim_account_id_provider_npi_id_idx" to remove 38136154 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 21.52 s, system: 0.98 s, elapsed: 159.36 s
INFO:  scanned index "claim_usage_code_idx" to remove 38136154 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 33.96 s, system: 1.63 s, elapsed: 144.92 s
INFO:  scanned index "claim_schedule_id_idx1" to remove 38136154 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 24.14 s, system: 1.10 s, elapsed: 64.30 s
INFO:  scanned index "claim_account_id_idx" to remove 38136154 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 13.53 s, system: 0.85 s, elapsed: 42.84 s
INFO:  scanned index "claim_claim_set_id_ref_ref_ordinal_key" to remove 38136154 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 8.18 s, system: 0.29 s, elapsed: 37.81 s
INFO:  scanned index "claim_usage_mapping_id_idx" to remove 38136154 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 11.94 s, system: 0.69 s, elapsed: 62.10 s
INFO:  "claim": removed 38136154 row versions in 7715817 pages
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 121.46 s, system: 3.13 s, elapsed: 351.33 s
INFO:  index "claim_pkey" now contains 6921839 row versions in 85211 pages
DETAIL:  16137555 index row versions were removed.
8093 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "claim_claim_set_id_external_id_idx" now contains 6921839 row versions in 251232 pages
DETAIL:  38136154 index row versions were removed.
134582 index pages have been deleted, 7101 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "claim_claim_set_id_idx" now contains 6921839 row versions in 159050 pages
DETAIL:  32725206 index row versions were removed.
77874 index pages have been deleted, 1705 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "claim_code_modifier_quantities_idx" now contains 6921839 row versions in 872749 pages
DETAIL:  38136154 index row versions were removed.
500736 index pages have been deleted, 28272 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "claim_account_id_provider_npi_id_idx" now contains 6921839 row versions in 346059 pages
DETAIL:  38136154 index row versions were removed.
101429 index pages have been deleted, 4627 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "claim_usage_code_idx" now contains 6921839 row versions in 381840 pages
DETAIL:  38136043 index row versions were removed.
242568 index pages have been deleted, 8961 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "claim_schedule_id_idx1" now contains 6921839 row versions in 185598 pages
DETAIL:  38136142 index row versions were removed.
121734 index pages have been deleted, 5088 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "claim_account_id_idx" now contains 6921839 row versions in 169603 pages
DETAIL:  38134646 index row versions were removed.
108740 index pages have been deleted, 5087 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "claim_claim_set_id_ref_ref_ordinal_key" now contains 6921839 row versions in 176903 pages
DETAIL:  19975782 index row versions were removed.
19912 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "claim_usage_mapping_id_idx" now contains 6921839 row versions in 138713 pages
DETAIL:  32942459 index row versions were removed.
69121 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  "claim": found 85733 removable, 6921839 nonremovable row versions in 8537156 out of 8537156 pages
DETAIL:  2 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 668246244
There were 15562466 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 380.79 s, system: 16.85 s, elapsed: 1880.08 s.
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_132182"
INFO:  scanned index "pg_toast_132182_index" to remove 198150 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 0.04 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.55 s
INFO:  "pg_toast_132182": removed 198150 row versions in 54329 pages
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 0.82 s, system: 0.01 s, elapsed: 2.49 s
INFO:  index "pg_toast_132182_index" now contains 132146 row versions in 1010 pages
DETAIL:  198150 index row versions were removed.
371 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  "pg_toast_132182": found 190401 removable, 112368 nonremovable row versions in 79637 out of 84372 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 668278370
There were 3794 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 4725 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 1.50 s, system: 0.05 s, elapsed: 6.25 s.
VACUUM
```

```
rivet=> select version();
                                   version                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.9.3, 64-bit
(1 row)

rivet=> show autovacuum;
 autovacuum 
------------
 on
(1 row)

rivet=> show log_autovacuum_min_duration;
 log_autovacuum_min_duration 
-----------------------------
 10s
(1 row)

rivet=> show autovacuum_max_workers;
 autovacuum_max_workers 
------------------------
 3
(1 row)

rivet=> show autovacuum_naptime;
 autovacuum_naptime 
--------------------
 5s
(1 row)

rivet=> show autovacuum_vacuum_threshold;
 autovacuum_vacuum_threshold 
-----------------------------
 50
(1 row)

rivet=> show autovacuum_analyze_threshold;
 autovacuum_analyze_threshold 
------------------------------
 50
(1 row)

rivet=> show autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor;
 autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor 
--------------------------------
 0.1
(1 row)

rivet=> show autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor;
 autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor 
---------------------------------
 0.05
(1 row)

rivet=> show autovacuum_freeze_max_age;
 autovacuum_freeze_max_age 
---------------------------
 200000000
(1 row)

rivet=> show autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age;
 autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age 
-------------------------------------
 400000000
(1 row)

rivet=> show autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay;
 autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay 
------------------------------
 5ms
(1 row)

rivet=> show autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit;
 autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit 
------------------------------
 600
(1 row)
```

How can I diagnose why autovacuum isn't actually vacuuming correctly?

Comment: Do you have log messages showing autovacuum failures ? If yes please post them: in these messages you could/should have messages explaining why autovacuum has failed.

Comment: Set log_autovacuum_min_duration to zero for a while.

Comment: Are you often using `LOCK` to explicitly lock the table?